# Freaky output: why would this code give any meaningful output, let alone this?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, cout, generic-programming

I'm not sure how to even state my question, but here we go...

So, I have this class for which `operator[]` has an empty body (not yet implemented). Still, when I call it from `main()`, it produces an output. What's more, the output is exactly what was assigned to it in the previous line.

`EDIT`: I added a private attribute called `emptyValue`, and I initialized it to `TipVrijednosti()` in class constructor.

Here's example:

```
  template<typename TipKljuca, typename TipVrijednosti>
    class BinStabloMapa : public Mapa<TipKljuca, TipVrijednosti>
    {
            .
            .
        TipVrijednosti &operator[] (const TipKljuca &kljuc) {
            return emptyValue;
        }
        const TipVrijednosti &operator[] (const TipKljuca &kljuc) const {
            return emptyValue;
        }
            .
            .
    }

    int main()
    {
        BinStabloMapa<int, int> m;
        m[100] = 200;
        cout << m[100] << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    OUTPUT: 200
```

Could anybody tell me why i this happening?

Comment: You could have used English in your code snippet too :P

Comment: Most probably a build issue or an issue when creating the question out of the real code. @P0W: Completely disagree, questions should have the real code that is failing, I am quite tired of people massaging code for the purpose of asking and hiding the issue in the meantime. I'd take real code in any language before wrong code in English any day.

Comment: What does TipVrijednosti() return?

Comment: What "freaky" compiler is used?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree, but this looks like this is an SSCCE, which could have been framed with a language known to all. And also it appears that you're aware of this very language. But its all "garbage" to someone who has never came across such language. (I know it has nothing to do with answers, but readability matters). Cheers !

Comment: @P0W: To be clear: I am not aware of that language at all. If I was to guess I'd say it looks like Polish or related, but I don't understand any of the identifiers, but you don't need to understand what `TipKljuca` means to know that it is the *key* into some form of a map (I would have used `K` for the template argument, which is not so much closer to English --deduced from the template argument and the type of the argument to `operator[]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour because you're not returning anything from a function that has a non-`void` return type.

§6.6.3:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

§1.3.24:

> **undefined behavior**
>   behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Comment: Ok, so I added the return statement, and nothing changed.

Comment: @IrfanKahvedzic Well what is `emptyValue`?

Comment: @IrfanKahvedzic If `emptyValue` is a member variable, now, as you seem to indicate, then you are no longer in UB-land. Since the `operator []` returns a reference to `emptyValue`, the line `m[100] = 200;` is actually assigning to it.

Comment: Well, since this is a generic class, I can't just return 0, because TipVrijednosti doesn't have to be an integer. Therefore I returned TipVrijednosti(), which is a call to it's constructor. (emptyValue=TipVrijednosti())

Comment: @SeanCline yeah, I figured as much, but wasn't completely sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not such a big puzzle.  Your `operator []` is returning a reference to some data variable called `emptyValue`.

```
            m[100] = 200;
```

is equivqlent to

```
            m.emptyValue = 200;
```

Then you write
                cout << m[100];

which is just like

```
            cout << m.emptyValue;
```

Note: the index '100' is irrelevant.

Comment: "Note: the index '100' is irrelevant." +1

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with that :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename TipKljuca, typename TipVrijednosti>
class BinStabloMapa /* : public Mapa<TipKljuca, TipVrijednosti> */ 
//comment inheritance to make it compile, not relevant to the problem
{
    //C++11 syntax, not relevant either
    TipVrijednosti emptyValue=TipVrijednosti();
    public:    
    TipVrijednosti &operator[] (const TipKljuca &kljuc) {
        return emptyValue;
    }
    const TipVrijednosti &operator[] (const TipKljuca &kljuc) const {
        return emptyValue;
    }


};

int main()
{
    BinStabloMapa<int, int> m;
    m[100] = 200; //calls no const operator[], thus emptyValue is changed 
    cout << m[100] << endl; //calls const operator[], thus emptyValue is return
    return 0;
}
```